# How to limit selected items in vue-select?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-select

I use [vue-select](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select) for multiple values.
Here is an example: https://codepen.io/sagalbot/pen/opMGro

I have the following code:

```
<v-select multiple v-model="selected" :options="options"></v-select>
```

And JS:

```
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: ['foo','bar'],
    options: ['foo','bar','baz']
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: What to limit??

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, selected tags

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `v-on:input` listener to see how many items are selected.

Then pass it a simple function as:

```
 <v-select multiple v-model="selected" :options="options" v-on:input="limiter"></v-select>
```

After this, create a function called `limiter` in your methods and you'll get the current list of selected inputs,as

```
  methods: {
    limiter(e) {
      if(e.length > 2) {
        console.log(' you can only select two', e)
        e.pop()
      }
    },
  }
```

Now, if you add more than 2 items then the last one will be remove and you will see the console log

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use inline condition:

```
<v-select multiple v-model="selected" :options="selected.length < 2 ? options: []">
```

I have limited to 2 options in the example above. The options will not be generated if there are 2 options selected. Remove the selected one and then you'll see the options dropdown.

Here's the updated [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVgwaY).

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
:selectable="() => selected.length < 3"
```

from the official documentation https://vue-select.org/guide/selectable.html#limiting-the-number-of-selections

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working for the vuetify v-select

Comment: he is using v-select package not vuetify. Both are different .