# Prevent vue select from displaying all options

Tags: vue.js, vue-select

I cannot seem to find a way to limit the size of the select field when multiple options are selected. I wish it was possible to see which options are selected only when the select field is focused.  Is there any way to prevent all options from being shown?  As you can see it looks terrible on small screens because the field width is small.

**Desktop**
[image]

**Mobile**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit selected items in vue-select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49155120/how-to-limit-selected-items-in-vue-select)

Comment: Not quite.  I guess using the `v-on:input` callback could allow me to store the selection without displaying it but it's definitely not ideal because the user would not be able to see that it's selected.

Comment: Have you tried with CSS?